# Unable to position content after setting CSS hover and blur effects

Tags: html, css, css-position

Landing page with class:showcase is set with blur after effect and works great. 
Set three styled buttons 2 future links to galleries and 1 mailto button.

I cant seem to position content after this in any way. 
Same in responsive view unable to push about and footer down.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks you

```css
body{
  background-color: #00091A;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

html{
  color: white;
  font-family: Caveat, cursive;
}

.title, .text{
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #B36C52;
}

.showcase::after{
  content: '';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(Pics/showcase.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.showcase:hover::after{
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}

.showcase:hover .content{
  filter: blur(3px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}

.content{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15%;
  left: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1000ms;
}

.content .logo{
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
}

.content .title{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.content .text{
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.button{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  left: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: Caveat, sans-serif;
  background: #CE5937;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, #004D59 10%, #001C21 50%, #000D0F 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, #004D59 10%, #001C21 50%, #000D0F 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at (center, #004D59 10%, #001C21 50%, #000D0F 100%);
}

footer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Danver's Tattoo</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="showcase">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="Pics/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>Welcome to Danver's Tattoo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>Here you will find some of the work done by Danver so far.<br>
            Planning to get a tattoo? Do you already know what you are getting?<br>
            Unsure what to get or how it works? Get in touch for a free consultation.
          </h3>
        </div class="navbar">
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="Color Tattoos" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="Click to Email Danver" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:zuperblack00@gmail.com'">
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="Black & White Tattoos" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
      </div>
      </header>

      <!-- About -->

      <section class="about">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="center">
              <h3>About Me</h3>
              <p>sjkkcvbsjbvsjbvsjbvsj</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

<footer class="center">
  Danver's tattoo &copy; 2020<br>
  Contact me on: zuperblack00@gmail.com
</footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what the problem is? Would you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: sorry about that. I am not able to center the about and footer elements in any way. They are simply stuck in one place. Cant figure out what command is overwriting/restricting any positioning to such level?

Comment: Ok it's probably the `:after` of `.showcase` element that is making the problem. and there's an image *( 'pics/showcase.jpg' )* in your css. What's that picture? Is it important? Do we really need `:after` at all?

Comment: I see. 1. Is there a way to override the issue without removing properties or the whole :after? 2. Picture is the background cover on landing page: when mouse cursor hovers out of page screen logo, three styled onclick buttons and small text are fully visible and cover photo is blurred out. when mouse cursor hovers within page screen its other way around. So yes the 2way blur effect was the whole concept of the landing page. thank you

Comment: or perhaps i should push the about and footer up in header with the rest of the elements, as it seems whatever is outside the effected screen becomes immovable?

Comment: I actually couldn't imagine your desired output. So I'm just giving you random answers. 1. If you make that `:after` a `position: absolute` element, your problem would be solved. 2. If you declare an `:after` for the whole `body` maybe there wouldn't be such problem anymore.

Comment: I will play around with these options. Thank you so much for your help.